# C++ game server

Tags: c++, game, networking, server, boost

I'm writing a server for an MMO game using boost::asio. I would like to know, are there any design or other issues in my code? And what should I improve in it? Thanks in advance.

**BaseServer.h:**

```
#ifndef BASE_SERVER_H
#define BASE_SERVER_H

#include <asio.hpp>
#include "MessageProcessor.h"

class BaseServer
{
public:
    BaseServer(asio::io_context& ioContext, unsigned short port)
        : socket(ioContext, asio::ip::udp::endpoint(asio::ip::udp::v4(), port))
    {
        receivePacket();
    }

protected:
    asio::ip::udp::socket socket;

    virtual void handlePacket() = 0;

private:
    void receivePacket()
    {
        socket.async_receive(asio::null_buffers(), [this](std::error_code ec, std::size_t bytes_recvd)
        {
            if (ec == asio::error::operation_aborted) return;
            handlePacket();
            receivePacket();
        });
    }
};

#endif
```

**GameServer.h:**

```
#ifndef GAME_SERVER_H
#define GAME_SERVER_H

#include <Net/BaseServer.h>
#include <Net/MessageProcessor.h>
#include <Utils/BitStream.h>

class GameServer : public BaseServer
{
public:
    GameServer(asio::io_context& ioContext, unsigned short port);

protected:
    MessageProcessor<BitStream&, asio::ip::udp::endpoint> messageProcessor;

    void asyncParsePacket(unsigned char* buffer, unsigned short packetSize, asio::ip::udp::endpoint senderEndpoint);
    virtual void handlePacket() override;
};

#endif
```

**GameServer.cpp:**

```
#include "GameServer.h"

#include <iostream>
#include "Messages/Client/TestMessage.h"

GameServer::GameServer(asio::io_context& ioContext, unsigned short port)
    : BaseServer(ioContext, port)
{
    messageProcessor.registerHandler(0x01, [](BitStream& stream, asio::ip::udp::endpoint endpoint)
    {
        TestMessage mes;
        mes.deserialize(stream);

        std::cout << "Test message received! A = " << mes.a << ", B = " << mes.b << std::endl;
    });
}

void GameServer::asyncParsePacket(unsigned char* buffer, unsigned short packetSize, asio::ip::udp::endpoint senderEndpoint)
{
    BitStream stream(buffer, packetSize);
    delete[] buffer;
    unsigned char messageId;
    stream >> messageId;

    auto handler = messageProcessor.getHandler(messageId);
    if (handler) handler(stream, senderEndpoint);
}

void GameServer::handlePacket()
{
    unsigned int available = socket.available();
    unsigned char* buffer = new unsigned char[available];
    asio::ip::udp::endpoint senderEndpoint;
    std::error_code ec;
    unsigned short packetSize = socket.receive_from(asio::buffer(buffer, available), senderEndpoint, 0, ec);
    socket.get_io_service().post(std::bind(&AuthServer::asyncParsePacket, this, buffer, packetSize, senderEndpoint));
}
```

**BaseMessage.h:**

```
#ifndef BASE_MESSAGE_H
#define BASE_MESSAGE_H

#include "../Utils/BitStream.h"

class BaseMessage
{
protected:
    unsigned short id;

public:
    BaseMessage(unsigned short messageId)
        : id(messageId) {}
    virtual ~BaseMessage() = default;

    unsigned short getId() const { return this->id; }

    virtual void serialize(BitStream& stream) const = 0;
    virtual void deserialize(BitStream& stream) = 0;
};

#endif
```

**MessageProcessor.h**

```
#ifndef MESSAGE_PROCESSOR_H
#define MESSAGE_PROCESSOR_H

#include <vector>
#include <functional>

class BitStream;

template <typename ... HandlerArgs>
class MessageProcessor
{
protected:
    using MessageHandler = std::function<void (HandlerArgs ...)>;
    std::vector<MessageHandler> messageHandlers;

public:
    void registerHandler(unsigned short id, MessageHandler handler)
    {
        if (messageHandlers.size() <= id) messageHandlers.resize(id);
        messageHandlers.insert(messageHandlers.begin() + id, handler);
    }

    MessageHandler getHandler(unsigned short id) const
    {
        return id < messageHandlers.size() ? messageHandlers[id] : 0;
    }
};

#endif
```

Comment: Can you tell us more about the current functionality and why you're doing what you're doing? For example, what's the purpose of 
`handlePacket()` and why is `receivePacket()` called recursively?

Comment: @Mast  `receivePacket()` is needed to encapsulate `async_read` function and avoid boilerplate code in derived classes. `handlePacket()` is like an `onMessageReceived()` callback. `receivePacket()` is called recursively because I need the server to receive messages in a loop.

Comment: Are you aware there's such a thing as recursion depth and exceeding the maximum depth will result in a stack overflow? What is your maximum stack size and how long have you tried running your server? It *should* crash eventually if I read this right.

Comment: @Mast This is not a recursion. `async_receive` is an asynchronous function, so it just adds new async request to the I/O queue and exits immediately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make the call to recieve_from async by creating a temp struct with the variables you need to keep alive and the buffer. Then you can put it in a shared_ptr (to account for the potential copies and capture that shared_ptr in the lambda:

```
void GameServer::handlePacket()
{
    unsigned int available = socket.available();
    struct rec_data{
        std::vector<unsigned char> buffer;
        asio::ip::udp::endpoint senderEndpoint;
    }

    std::shared_ptr<rec_data> data = std::make_shared<rec_data>();
    data->buffer.resize(available);

    socket.receive_from(asio::buffer(data ->buffer.data(), available), 
         data ->senderEndpoint, 0, 
         [data](const std::error_code& error, 
                std::size_t bytes_transferred)
         {
             if(!error)
                 asyncParsePacket(data->buffer.data(), bytes_transferred, data->senderEndpoint);
         });
}
```

The int you use for `registerHandler` is a magic number. Make it an enum and give each message type a name. Make sure to share the header between the sender and receiver.